# log4j logging. 2 appenders, 2 loggers same package, 2nd logger output unsatisfactory

Tags: logging, log4j

I've trawled SO for an answer to this and surprisingly haven't seen my exact issue.  In a nutshell:

I need to log output to 2 separate files, outputA.log & outputB.log.

OutputA will record the footprints of each transaction.

OutputB.log will only record timings of operations.

The log statements must not crossover into the other logfile.

Now, I have mostly got this working.  My log4j has 2 appenders for the files, and 2 loggers for recording the logs.

My loggers are defined as:

```
<logger name="com.mypackage">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="OutputA_Appender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="TIMING_LOG" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="OutputB_Appender"/>
</logger>
```

Which is fine.  The log contents are segregated from each other.  However, invoking the loggers is a bit problematic - assume the class is called SomeClassDoingStuff.java:

```
>     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClassDoingStuff.class);   
> 
>     private static final Logger LOGGER_TIMINGS= LoggerFactory.getLogger"TIMING_LOG");
```

The problem is the difference in log output; from LOGGER:

```
[2016-11-24 15:40:41,611] [thread-1] [someId=1252] [INFO ] [com.mypackage.SomeClassDoingStuff] My log message: foo!
```

from LOGGER_TIMINGS:

```
[2016-11-24 16:05:38,694] [thread-1] [someId=1252] [INFO ] [TIMING_LOG] My log message: Bar! (ms): 340
```

While LOGGER gives me the pacjage + class name on the log statement (from the %c parameter in the conversion pattern), LOGGER_TIMINGS prints out "TIMING_LOG" which isn't useful.  I can get the name of the called using %C in the conversion pattern, but as it's a time sensitive system I, err, can't!

Any thoughts on how the second logger (LOGGER_TIMINGS) can print out the package+classname?

Comment: Not much in the way of footfall on this question.  I suppose Thanksgiving Day is a bad day to ask a question...

Comment: Can you please post the full configuration ?